# Global tempered A-parameter is the same with generic A-parameter?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

It seems there are two relevant terminologies on global Arthur parameter. One is generic A-parameter and the other one is tempered A-parameter.

I thought that these two terminology are same. But is seems that while globally generic automorphic representation belongs to some generic A-packet, it may not belong to any tempered A-packet.

Are they same or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what the definitions are?  It is generally expected on this site that you put a reasonable amount of effort into figuring something out yourself before asking a question here (and it's also better for you).  I think if you look up the definitions the answer should be clear (if not, it is okay to ask here, but also explain the definitions and why you are not sure if they are the same).

Comment: @Kimball, Thank you for your comment! The definition of the generic A-parameter appears in Arthur's book, that is a formal sum of representation of product of linear groups and $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that trivial on $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Though I didn't see any reference where the precise definition of tempered A-parameter where it is written, I guess from its name that it is some A-parameter whose A-packet consisting only of tempered representations. But a generic A-packet consists of irreducible representations tempered almost everywhere but finite places and generic at such finite places.

Comment: My advice is don't make guesses about this stuff---it's quite delicate and a lot is still conjectural.  E.g., global A-parameters (in terms of the Langlands group) are conjectural, so Arthur and others have to substitute formal parameters for the endoscopic classification.  If you're reading a paper that talks about tempered global A-parameters, look at their definitions carefully to see what they really mean.

Comment: @Kimball, Thanks to your advice, I could find the definition of tempered A-parameter in some paper and found that its definition is same with that of generic A-parameter. I am very sorry for such hasty question. May I ask you another question? By the endoscopic classification of Arthur and others, every tempered representation is contained in some generic A-packet. But it is likely that there may be some non-tempered representation in generic A-packet. Is it right?

Comment: Generic packets should consist of tempered representations.  The obstruction to proving this is Ramanujan conjecture.

Comment: @Kimball, Oh, I see! Thank you very much for your comments!